# Racket, change the elements in the list of list

Tags: racket

How can I change the elements in the list of list?

Edit:

I partially solved the problem

```
(define a (list
           (list 1 2 3)
           (list 4 5 6)
           (list 7 8 9)
           )
  )
(define (list-change alist row column value)
  (cond
    [(= row 0) (list-set (first alist) column value)]
    [(= row 1) (list-set (second alist) column value)]
    [(= row 2) (list-set (third alist) column value)]
  )
  )
(list-change a 0 0 100)
```

This function return

> '(100 2 3)

But, I want to return the whole list

Comment: It depends on the variation of the input. If you know it's 3x3 you just do the same as you have done in *to*, but I guess there is more to it than that? Please edit your question with more information on a specific problem with the variation on the inputs and the expected output.

Comment: If you need to do this a lot you probably want vectors rather than lists.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, here you go:

```
;; given a list, return the desired output list
;; list-of-list-of-numbers -> list-of-list-of-numbers
(define (change lon)
  (list (list 1 2 3)
        (list 4 5 6)
        (list 7 8 9)))

;; let's check that it works:
(check-expect
 (change (list (list 1 1 1)
               (list 1 1 1)
               (list 1 1 1)))
 (list (list 1 2 3)
       (list 4 5 6)
       (list 7 8 9)))
```

I'm only half trolling you; "setting" and "returning a new list" are probably synonyms in this setting.